# I get this error in Unity, can anyone help me?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code

```
public class cameramover : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject player;
    public Vector2 playerpos;
    public Vector2 campos;

    void Start()
    {
        playerpos = player.transform.position;
        campos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        campos.x + 30 - playerpos.x;
        campos.y - playerpos.y;

    }
}
```

And I get this error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

Can you help me? And tell me what I did wrong

Comment: I mean the error is fairly clear you just need to look at it carefully `campos.x + 30 - playerpos.x;` doesn't satisfy "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement".

Comment: Can you please explain what you don't understand from multiple other answers you read when you've searched for error message? It is generally good idea to *demonstrate in the post* results of your research rather than simply post error message and wall of code (and not [MCVE])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not assigning your calculation:

```
campos.x + 30 - playerpos.x;
campos.y - playerpos.y;
```

If you change it to the following it will work:

```
campos.x += 30 - playerpos.x; //campos will be campos + (30 - playerpos.x)
campos.y -= playerpos.y; //Uses campos.y minus the playerpos.y
```

The problem is you are using a calculation without assigning the output.

Answer (score 2):

The error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

Means the following lines can not be in your code.

```
campos.x + 30 - playerpos.x;
campos.y - playerpos.y;
```

So you will need to add the = operator in those expressions

```
campos.x += 30 - playerpos.x;
campos.y -= playerpos.y;
```